# hasOwnProperty('getTime') returns false on date object

Tags: javascript, properties, prototype

```
const test = new Date()
test.hasOwnProperty('getTime') // false
'getTime' in test // true
```

this means that `getTime` is not in the prototype of `test` (not it's own prototype), but further up the hierarchy (because `in` works). Why is that, I cannot find a reference explaining this. Is this due to how the getTime "property" is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` doesn't look up the prototype chain:

> Every object descended from [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) inherits the `hasOwnProperty` method. This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty))

This is why `hasOwnProperty` is often used to check if a property exists, in 
[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Examples) loops:

```
for (key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
    // do stuff with obj[key]
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, `getTime` is a property of `Date.prototype` so `Date.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getTime')` would return true.

Answer (score 0):

`getTime` its in prototype so it gives false when you using `in` operator it delegates through the prototype chain and if finds any property return true otherwise false

Comment: @MJB it happens for everybody:)