# Confused about "hasOwnProperty" for detecting existence of functions

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find the right search terms to find an answer.

I'm trying to use `hasOwnProperty()` to determine if a function exists on an object or not. I know there are other ways to do this, but I want to understand why that method doesn't work the way I was expecting.

I typed this into a Chrome Dev Tools console:

```
window.hasOwnProperty("getSelection")
<- true

window.getSelection().hasOwnProperty("empty")
<- false
```

What I don't understand is why `hasOwnProperty("empty")` returns `false`, when that method *does* exist on the `Selection` object and I can call it.

```
window.getSelection().empty()  // Returns no errors
```

Comment: `"empty" in window.getSelection()` returns true. So, it's inherited, from somewhere down the prototype chain: [hasOwnProperty('getTime') returns false on date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112458) and  [if (key in object) or if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632999)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getSelection` returns a Selection object instance, which has an *internal prototype* of `Selection.prototype`. The prototype has the `empty` method on it; it's not on the instance itself:

```js
const sel = window.getSelection();
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(sel) === Selection.prototype,
  Selection.prototype.hasOwnProperty("empty")
);
```

If you wanted to implement this sort of thing yourself:

```js
class Foo {
  method() {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();

console.log(
  f.hasOwnProperty('method'),
  Foo.prototype.hasOwnProperty('method')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's not a property on that object, rather it's inherited. Inherited properties are not the object's *own* properties, as they come from the constructor or class. Far better is the `in` keyword:

```js
console.log("getSelection" in window);
console.log("empty" in window.getSelection());
```